# Parallel looping over multiple lists lme4

Tags: r, lapply, purrr, lme4

I am trying to run multi-level models over a number of variables. I have two lists of variables - outcome and response. What I'm having difficulty with is setting up the lapply command to run each element of the list in parallel. So the first element of the list "outcome" runs at the same time as the first element of the list "response". Then for the second element of the list "outcome", the second element of the list "response" is called.

I have been able to combine 2 lapply commands but this gives me every combination of each element from the outcome and response list which is not ideal. I can manually extract the elements I want but is there another way to achieve this?

```r
#Define random intercept
random_intercepts <- "(1|clusters)"

#For each of the 4 outcome variables, define the response variables
water_imp_vars <- c("fish_factor", "num_childrenunder5", "quintile_nowashnomat_fac")
less5_vars <- c("fish_factor", "num_hh_members", "num_childrenunder5")
san_imp_vars <- c("fish_factor", "num_hh_members", "num_childrenunder5", "quintile_nowashnomat_fac")
housing_imp_vars <- c("fish_factor","num_hh_members", "num_childrenunder5", "quintile_nowashnomat_fac")

#Combine all repsonse variables into 1 list
all_response <- list(water_imp_vars, less5_vars, san_imp_vars, housing_imp_vars)

#List of outcomes 
outcomes <- c("water_imp", "less_than_5", "san_imp", "housing_imp")


all_models <- lapply(setNames(outcomes, outcomes), function(var) {
  lapply(all_response, function(var2) {
    fixed <- paste0(var2, collapse= "+")
    formula <- as.formula(paste(var, "~", fixed, "+", random_intercepts))
    glmer(formula, hr_analysis_dataset, family='binomial', nAGQ = 0)
  })
})
```

Here is some of the output from the all_models variable.

```r
$water_imp
$water_imp[[1]]
water_imp ~ fish_factor + num_childrenunder5 + quintile_nowashnomat_fac + 
    (1 | clusters)
<environment: 0x0000000017ecdd58>

$water_imp[[2]]
water_imp ~ fish_factor + num_hh_members + num_childrenunder5 + 
    (1 | clusters)
<environment: 0x0000000017ed1858>

$water_imp[[3]]
water_imp ~ fish_factor + num_hh_members + num_childrenunder5 + 
    quintile_nowashnomat_fac + (1 | clusters)
<environment: 0x0000000017ed5f20>

$water_imp[[4]]
water_imp ~ fish_factor + num_hh_members + num_childrenunder5 + 
    quintile_nowashnomat_fac + (1 | clusters)
<environment: 0x0000000017ed86a0>
```

I am only interested in the first combination for the first outcome variable --

```r
water_imp ~ fish_factor + num_childrenunder5 + quintile_nowashnomat_fac + 
    (1 | clusters)
```

and then for the second outcome variable, I am interested in the second combination

```r
less_than_5 ~ fish_factor + num_hh_members + num_childrenunder5 + 
    (1 | clusters)
```

Although it is not a lot of work to extract the correct combination, I am also planning to run this analysis for a number of countries so this problem will continue to grow once additional levels are added.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: `lapply` does not run in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want four models and to run them in parallel? The formula part is simple:

```
results <- lapply(1:4, function(i){
  fixed <- paste0(unlist(all_response[i]), collapse= " + ")
  formula <- as.formula(paste(outcomes[i], "~", fixed, "+", random_intercepts))
  print(formula)
  glmer(formula, hr_analysis_dataset, family='binomial', nAGQ = 0)
})
```

But these will not run in parallel. For that you would need to use a parallel lapply function like:

```
library(parallel)
# Calculate the number of cores
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

# Initiate cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores, type="FORK")

results <- parLapply(cl, 1:4, function(i){
  fixed <- paste0(unlist(all_response[i]), collapse= " + ")
  formula <- as.formula(paste(outcomes[i], "~", fixed, "+", random_intercepts))
  print(formula)
  glmer(formula, hr_analysis_dataset, family='binomial', nAGQ = 0)
})

stopCluster(cl)
```

Note that this only applies to linux based systems that can use FORK. Otherwise, if on windows, you have to use PSOCK. see [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/) for a more detailed overview of parallel lapply in R.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for your help. One slight adjustment. The code you suggested led to formulas that looked like this -

```r
 "water_imp ~ c("fish_factor", "num_childrenunder5",  "quintile_nowashnomat_fac") + (1 | clusters)". 
```

To get around this, I changed the response variable strings from individual variables

```r
water_imp_vars <- c("fish_factor", "num_childrenunder5", "quintile_nowashnomat_fac")
```

 to one long string

```r
water_imp_vars <- ("fish_factor + num_childrenunder5 + quintile_nowashnomat_fac")
```

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Ah yes, we needed to unlist the variables before collapsing...I've edited my answer to fix the bug. Please mark as correct and upvote if you are happy with it...it adds to my reputation :)